# Dual boot on Dell E5470

Tags: 16.04, dual-boot, bios

I have made my USB into Ubuntu 16.04 bootable.
But when I give try Ubuntu without installing, I get a gray screen. I do not get anything. I have tried disabling Secure Boot, disabling Fast boot and also upgaded the latest version of BIOS.
But it doesn't seem to solve the problem. Please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it. Had to remove legacy ROM since system was basically UEFI